# TreeMap<String,(new TreeMap<String,Integer>()) Treemap With Object

Tags: java, collections, treemap

Hi I have the following code

```
TreeMap mp = new TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>();
mp.put(line,(new TreeMap<String,Integer>()));
```

Now if i want to insert data into the new EmptyTree<String,Integer> that was created by "mp", how do i do that?

Comment: What type is `mp`? What is `EmptyTree`? Did you mean `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a myriad of ways to do that.

First, you could simply keep a reference around:

```java
var map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
mp.put(line, map);
// can du stuff with map now
```

Second, you could read the value back from the map - obviously that is not very efficient, but I'd include it for completeness sake:

```java
mp.put(line,(new TreeMap<String,Integer>()));
var map = mp.get(line);
```

The most elegant solution would be to use `computeIfAbsent`:

```java
var map = mp.computeIfAbsent(line, line -> new TreeMap<String,Integer>());
// do stuff with map
```

`computeIfAbsent` returns the value that is already present in the map, or otherwise evaluates the lambda and puts that into the map, and returns that value.

From the JavaDoc:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to `null`), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless `null`.
>
> If the mapping function returns null, no mapping is recorded. If the mapping function itself throws an (unchecked) exception, the exception is rethrown, and no mapping is recorded. The most common usage is to construct a new object serving as an initial mapped value or memoized result, as in:
> `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Value(f(k)));`
>
> Or to implement a multi-value map, `Map<K,Collection<V>>`, supporting multiple values per key:
> `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);`
>
> The mapping function should not modify this map during computation

The advantage of `computeIfAbsent` is that you do not need to check if the value is already present in the map, and don't have the danger of overriding old values.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve it using [`TreeMap#get(java.lang.Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) and put the value using one of the put methods from the retrieved `TreeMap` such as [`TreeMap#put(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put(K,%20V)).

Example:

```
// notice the diamond operator used here -- it improves your code readability!!
TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> mp = new TreeMap<>();

// you don't need to qualify the type again because of the diamond operator
mp.put(line, new TreeMap<>());

// put a new value into the newly created TreeMap
Integer value = 1;
mp.get(line).put("your string key", value);
```

For the sake of completeness: If you use Java 8 or newer, to make the code even cleaner you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):.

```
TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> mp = new TreeMap<>();

Integer value = 1;
mp.computeIfAbsent(line, key -> new TreeMap<>()).put("your string key", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you posted has multiple problems:

```
TreeMap mp = new TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>();
       ^ add type specifier                           ^missing `>`
```

In the first line, you did not specify the generic type, so your `mp` is a rawtype - therefore invoking `get` on it returns something of type `Object` - to use this would require casting, and is not recommended. Valid versions are:

```
TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> mp = new TreeMap<>();
```

or

```
var mp = new TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>>();
```

both of these versions allow you to access the nested maps without casts:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> m = mp.get(line);
```

But, as others have already mentioned, to put a value in a map in case it is absent, but use the existing value otherwise, is exactly what the method [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) is for - using that you can write, for example:

```
    var line = "line";      
    var mp = new TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>>();     
    var m = mp.computeIfAbsent(line, k -> new TreeMap<>());
    m.put("content", 5);
    System.out.println(mp);
```

Output:

```
{line={content=5}}
```